# Dropdown selected with URL parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url-parameters

How can I have my dropdown selected with an url parameter?
I found this: 
[Dropdown selected based on URL parameter - PHP or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23591754/dropdown-selected-based-on-url-parameter-php-or-jquery?lq=1)

But it does not work for me. What am I doing wrong?
My url would be:

```
kontakt.php?Betreff=3
```

script:

```
var val = location.href.match(/[?&]Betreff=(.*?)[$&]/)[1];   // get params from URL
$('#Betreff').val(val);   //  assign URL param to select field
```

and:

```
<select class="mailstyle" name="Betreff" id="Betreff">
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You mean you are not able to see the `option` with `value` equal to `3` selected?

Comment: Yes, it is always value 1 that is selected!

Comment: That regex only works if you have more than 1 parameters, like `http://example.com/Betreff=3&Inhalt=something`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect. You can use this function ([from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582512/how-to-get-url-parameters-with-javascript)) to get the parameter value:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}
```

You can then use that to set the value:

```
var val = getURLParameter('Betreff');
$('#Betreff').val(val);   //  assign URL param to select field
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var val = location.href.match(/[?&]Betreff=(.*?)(?:$|&)/)[1];   // get params from URL
$('#Betreff').val(val);   //  assign URL param to select field
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#Betreff option').each(function(){
    if($(this).val()==val){
        $(this).attr("selected","selected");
        break; 
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks you for your effort! But Rory McCrossan answer was exactly what I was looking for!